# Problemas con constructor

Tags: java

Hola estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio de DAW y me estoy volviendo loco con el constructor, netbeans me pide un retorno y me da error, ese constructor deberia crear una instancia con los atributos estanteria, balda y numeroLibro y titulo.

```
/**
 * Libro.java
 * Definición de la clase Libro
 * ============================
 * 
 * @autor Luis Quesada Romero
 */

package GestionLibreria;

public class Libro { // Clase principal Libro

    // Atributos de objeto /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private String estanteria;
    private String balda;
    private String numeroLibro;
    private String codArt = estanteria + balda + numeroLibro;
    private String titulo;
    private int unidadesTotales;

    // Atributos de clase //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static final int DIGITOS_ESTANTERIA = 3;
    public static final int DIGITOS_BALDA = 2;
    public static final int DIGITOS_NRI_LIBRO = 5;
    public static final int DIGITOS_DC = 2;

    // Métodos privados ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Método setter
     * Establecemos los abritutos del libro: estanteria, balda y codigoLibro
     * 
     * @param CLIBC - Es el código completo del libro que introduce el
     * usuario por teclado en el programa
     */

    public void establecerLibro (String CLIBC) {
        this.estanteria = CLIBC.substring(0, 3);
        this.balda = CLIBC.substring(3, 5);
        this.numeroLibro = CLIBC.substring(5, 10);
    }

     /**
     * Método setter
     * Establecemos el título del libro
     * 
     * @param titulo - Es el titulo del libro
     */

    public void establecerTitulo (String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    // MÉTODO CONSTRUCTOR //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
    * Método setter
    * Establecemos el título del libro
    * 
    * @param titulo - Es el titulo del libro
    */

    public ConstructorLibro (String CLIBC, String titulo) {
        establecerLibro(CLIBC);
        establecerTitulo(titulo);
    }


} // Fin clase principal Libro
```

Como nota deciros que CLIBC es el codigo que le pido al usuario cuando ejecuta el programa y de el saco balda, estanteria y numero de libro, y el enunciado me pide que en el constructor llame a esos dos métodos para establecer el valor de los atributos, gracias

Comment: que no en Java, si la clase se llama `Libros` el constructor se debe llamar del mismo modo? `Libros` ?

Comment: efectivamente el constructor debe llamarse igual que la clase, estudiar a las 4 de la madrugada tiene sus problemas.
¿de esa forma ya tengo los atributos o como tengo que hacerlo?

Comment: un constructor debe inicializar los valores que la clase va a recibir, mas o menos así: `class Libro
{
 public int anio;
 public int ISBN;

 public Libro(int anio, int ISBN)
 {
  this.anio = anio;
  this.ISBN = ISBN;
 }
}`

Comment: Eso mas o menos lo tengo claro, pero en este caso me estoy liando con el con constructor, ya que me dice el ejercicio que cuando lo llame le paso como parametros CLIBC y titulo, que es lo que me introduce el usuario por teclado.

Y luego llamo a los metodos establecerLibro y establecerTitulo para asignar valor a los atributos estanteria, balda, numeroLibro y titulo.

Es justo eso lo que no se, como establecerlos, gracias

Comment: Creo que deberias dormir.. y mirarlo despierto.. porque todo lo que decis esta escrito ahi...

Comment: > private String codArt = estanteria + balda + numeroLibro;

* Esa linea no va a funcionar, definele el valor en el constructor
* Solo las vriables estaticas-finales deben ir en mayusculas, "CLIBC" no debería

Answer (score 4):

El constructor se debe llamar **Libro**, no **ConstructorLibro**. Algo así:

```
public Libro(String CLIBC, String titulo) {
...
}
```

Me parece que debes leer un poco de java básico.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dijeron mas arriba, siempre el constructor de la clase (tengas 1 o mas) tienen que tener el mismo nombre que la clase. 
Por ejemplo:

```
public class ClaseEjemplo{
/*... atributos y demas***/
   public ClaseEjemplo(){ //El constructor tiene que tener el nombre de la clase.
   /*...codigo...*/
}
```

}